# Installing IIS after .NET framework 3.5 has been installed

Tags: iis-6

I'm aware of the procedure mentioned here to re-register ASP.NET if IIS is installed after the .NET framework has been installed:

http://www.mike-tech.com/article.php?gif=iis&article=281

However, most of these articles are old and refer to ASP.NET as part of the .NET framework v1. On the system I'm looking at here are **four** verion folders:

v1.0.3705 - doesn't have aspnet_regiis.exe in it
v1.1.4322 - does have aspnet_regiis.exe and I assume is the main folder for .NET v1.x
v2.0.50727 - does have aspnet_regiis.exe and I assume is the main folder for .NET v2.x
v3.0 - not in here
v3.5 - not in here either

Do I have to re-register both v1 and v2? If so, in which order?

Also, when I install IIS on this Windows 2003 server, the ASP.NET checkbox isn't checked. This refers to ASP.NET v1 doesn't it? I'm going to check it anyway although I assumed that as .NET v3.5 had already been installed, ASP.NET was already there. Or is ASP.NET in this case a specific part of IIS?

Cheers, Rob.

Comment: Later - the process installs ASP.NET and then requires a DLL to be registered. This only works with the v1 DLL. With the v2, it complains that DllRegisterServer entry point was not found. So maybe DLL registrated is only needed with ASP.NET v1

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to register what ever version the application was written in (v1 or v2).  V3 and v3.5 are simply addons to v2 (stupid I know).